# Increasing the size of $state.store.object in a vue.js project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm just learning vue and I see that the application I'm working on fetches data from a db then puts it into a list like this before it binds and displays it on the page:

```js
if (response.data.length > 1) {
  this.list.push(...response.data)
  $state.loaded()
  if (response.data == 0) {
    $state.complete()
  }
} else {
  $state.complete()
}
```

where the list collection below is in the script section of the .vue page.

```js
export default {

  computed: {
    list: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.records.list
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('records/listUpdate', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem, when I fetch all data ~81K results and try and push them I get an error in the console that says:

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at Array.mutator (vue.js:883)
>       at ....\record-search.vue:909

Each object isn't that big and I can put the 'response.data' into a new Javascript array [] without any errors.

Question - can I increase the size of the '$state.store.records' where the data is being held so that I don't get this error and can display all 81K results in the page? I don't mind if it takes a few seconds to render, I have a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `this.list` value at one go, rather then `.push` all 81k items into it:

```js
this.list = [].concat(this.list, response.data);
```

Comment: ya that works, but it now it's taking forever to render on the screen. It's still working.....after a couple of minutes. The query to fetch the data only takes about 3 seconds to fetch from the database.

Comment: Well, what did you expect? 81k items would be quite heavy to render :)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Vue, is there a way to speed this up. The clients want to speed things up and currently there is a infinite scroll that fetches only 50 results at a time. Being there could be 81K results, it would take a lifetime to scroll down 81K results. The old app fetched into a file then display from the file. I was thinking Vue could just render it into a simple table, wouldn't that be quick?

Comment: I don't care if it takes up to 10-15 seconds, I can display a spinner or something, but I hav eit running now for a couple of minutes and it still hasn't finished displaying the results on the screen

Comment: You forgot that Vue adds reactivity and builds DOM. I'd suggest you to consider pagination, because 81k results on one page is never good.

Comment: I'm not familar with how Vue works, I've never used it before. I would think if these are simple results, just a couple of strings of data, then 81K results should render pretty fast (~5-10 sec)

Comment: How many rows are we talking about here?  The rendering in Vue is quick.  2 possible reasons if it's slow.  1. There are too many rows.  2. There is something else slowing it down during the rendering.  Comment out the code step by step.  For example, make it redner only 1 column, then 2 column, then 3.  You will find out why it is slow.